# Регистрация на сайте, нужен ваш совет

Tags: регистрация

Делаю систему регистрации на своём сайте. Как лучше выполнять подтверждение почтового адреса пользователя? Два варианта:

1. Высылать на почту пароль к учетной записи (логином является сам почтовый адрес), в этом случае шагов для регистрации меньше и посетителю не придется придумывать пароль, он придет на почту, и если пароль будет введен правильно значит это действительно его почта, этот код будет паролем и одновременно кодом подтверждения. Недостаток в том, что пароль будет вида 1fghJf4 и посетитель никогда его не сможет запомнить, если захочет зайти в свою запись повторно.
2. Высылать на почту отдельно код подтверждения, а пароль пусть придумывает отдельно и вводит дополнительно. В этом случае ему проще будет его запомнить, но добавляется ещё один шаг регистрации.

Comment: 1 шаг с возможностью изменить пароль после регистрации, либо сразу во время регистрации, если юзер захочет

Comment: @Dantessss спасибо за совет, учту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы выбирал второй вариант. И что мешает вводит пароль при вводе почты, а на почту присылать код подтверждения? Не надо все усложнять без необходимости. Чем процесс регистрации проще тем лучше. Первый вариант хорош лишь тем, что не придется беспокоится за безопасность пароля, но подумайте сами, захочется ли вам лезть в почту, копировать пароль, чтобы зайти на сайт?

Я считаю вариант с предложением изменить автогенерируемый пароль в процессе излишним - чем проще тем лучше.

Comment: Благодарю, учту. Хочу добавить что пароль с логином, сохранятся в виде вечного куки в браузере.

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов плохая практика. Во первых пароль должен храниться в хешированном виде и даже вы (хозяин сайта) не должны знать пароль в чистом виде. Во вторых, в куки должен храниться ключ,а не логин + пароль. Пользователь будет проходить аутентификацию по этому ключи, а при выходе ключ должен удаляться.

Comment: спасибо, не знал, А пароль хешировать от взломщиков?

Comment: @ИгорьСаламов формально да. Если кто-то получит доступ к базе, то он и получит пароль и сможет войти в систему под любым пользователем. Куки являются также слабым местов в системе безопасности, поскольку тоже могут быть запросто угнаны. Именно по этому, на сайтах, где требуется повышенная безопасность, используется сессия, которая краткосрочная и, как правило, живет в течении одного сеанса.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос про подтверждение мыла или уменьшение шагов регистрации?

На форме регистрации два поля - мыло и пароль. После отправки юзер сразу становится авторизованным, а на мыло падает письмо с одноразовой ссылкой (токеном) переход по которой подтвердит мыло.

Итого полтора шага.